# Localization at runtime at above android Jelly bean

Tags: android, localization

I want to change language of my app at runtime.
    I have searched many questions on SO and use given code but this code only works below jelly bean. What should i do for jelly bean and above.

```
 Resources res = getContext().getResources();
                // Change locale settings in the app.
                DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
                android.content.res.Configuration conf = new Configuration(res.getConfiguration());
                 conf.locale = nLocale;
                res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
                getActivity().recreate();
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Locale locale = new Locale(language);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Resources resources = context.getResources();
        Configuration configuration = resources.getConfiguration();
        configuration.locale = locale;
        resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, resources.getDisplayMetrics());
```

Comment: Pass String language Like 'hi' and 'en'

Comment: it is not working on android sdk Jelly Bean or above

Comment: i did using this line   getActivity().recreate();  but nothing happend

Comment: Thanks it solved my problem. actually i did same code the problem was i was sending wrong locale code